# Google Maps API v3 Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I cannot get Google Maps to display for the life of me. I have been going over the code for hours, I am all but certain I am not missing anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Profile</title>
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:type" content=""/>
<meta property="og:url" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:description" content=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<style>
  article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header,
  hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
     <div id="logo">
    </div>
  </header>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=true"></script>

  <div id="profile">

    <div id="info">

    </div>


        <div class="map" id="map4" style=""></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        var map4 = document.getElementById('map4');
        var map4_bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
        var map4_center = new google.maps.LatLng(30.27, -86);
        var map4_geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var map4_window;
        var map4_markers = [];
        var map4_windows = [];
        var map4_html = [];
        var map4_count = 0;



        var map4_options = {
            center: map4_center,
            draggable: false, 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
            maxZoom: 15, 
            minZoom: 10, 
            scrollwheel: false, 
            zoom: 12
            }

        var map4_canvas = new google.maps.Map(map4, map4_options);
        (function () {  /* Fixes a known bug with Google's API with displaying the InfoWindow(s) */

        new_location = false;
            new_latitude = '30.27';
            new_longitude = '-86';

            if(new_latitude != '' && new_longitude != '') {

            new_location = new google.maps.LatLng(new_latitude, new_longitude);                         
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map4_canvas, 
            position: new_location
        });


            map4_html[map4_count] = "Indianapolis, IN";
        map4_markers[map4_count] = marker;
        map4_count++;
            }
                    if(new_location) {
                    map4_canvas.setZoom(12)
                    map4_canvas.setCenter(new_location)

                }
            if(new_location) {

                var html = "Indianapolis, IN"       
                if(map4_html[map4_count-1] == "" || map4_html[map4_count] == "{title}")
                    map4_html[map4_count-1] = html;

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: html
                });

                map4_windows[map4_count-1] = infowindow;                
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map4_canvas, marker);
                    map4_window = infowindow;
                });
            }})(); /* End bug fix */

        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What in the world could I possibly be doing wrong? No matter what I try, the map area just keeps coming up blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why should it display? You didn't specify any size of your map4 div element and it has no content, so its size is 0x0.

Comment: Wow, unbelievable. I knew it had to be something ridiculously easy like that. Thank you so much!!!